# Detect if browser has smooth scrolling feature already

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, browser-detection

I have added smooth scrolling to a site of mine using this piece of JavaScript when clicking on hash links.

```
$('a[href*=#]')
    .click(onAnchorClick);

function onAnchorClick(event)
{
    return ! scrollTo(this.hash);
}


function scrollTo(target)
{
    var e = $(target);
    var y = e.exists() ? e.offset().top : 0;

    if(y == 0 && target != '#top')
        return false;

    if(Math.max($('html').scrollTop(), $('body').scrollTop()) != y)
        $('html,body')
            .animate({scrollTop: y}, 500, function() { location.hash = target; } );
    else
        location.hash = target;

    return true;
}

$.fn.exists = function()
{
    return this.length > 0 ? this : false;
}
```

Works fantastic in desktop browsers and looks to work fine on at least iOS devices as well. However, on my WinPhone 8 device it was garbage. Scrolling was a mess and didn't even end up where it should. So I decided to not enable it there through an `if( ! /Windows Phone 8\.0/.test(navigator.userAgent))`.

Now it works well, and seems the browser on the WinPhone actually is smooth scrolling by default, which is great.

But it is of course a bit dumb to have a smooth scroll script active if the browser already does this by default. Is there a way I can detect if a browser already has a smooth scrolling feature enabled?

Comment: Maybe in each animation step check whether the `.scrollTop` still has the value you've assigned to it before. That of course would require doing it manually, not with `.animate()`, of course, but shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Bergi - ( I know this is 5 years later, but...) An unfortunate side effect of the implementation that is put in place is that it misuses the wheel event for these smooth scrolling events. When the user moves the mouse wheel once, smooth scrolling continuously fires wheel events in order to scroll from. However, the user is not actually moving the wheel.

Comment: @TravisJ Luckily now there is also a CSS alternative! Added it as a new accepted answer |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several years later, there now is a CSS property in the Working Draft for this:

> [`scroll-behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)

So instead of the Javascript in my original question, or similar, we can just do this:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  html {
    scroll-behavior: auto;
  }
}
```

Right now, it seems to work for all browsers except IE and Edge, and since this is just a nice-to-have feature that makes things look a bit nicer... Yeah, I don't really care about IE or Edge.

Comment: Unfortunately chrome doesn't seem to abide by this css flag, and will still use the smooth scrolling behavior even when auto is set.

Comment: @TravisJ Works fine in my Chrome.

Comment: My test case still comes back triggering smooth scrolling when auto is set (auto should default to non smooth). I didn't test the enforcement of the inverse (the enabling of smooth scrolling), which is what I assume you mean "works fine".

Comment: Yeah. `auto` to me sounds like "whatever the browser/os has decided is the default", and `smooth` forces smooth scrolling. So, I guess for your case there's a missing state of `off` or `unsmooth` or something like that ‍♂️

Answer (score 8):

I managed to solve it this way:

```html
<style>
  body {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
</style>

<script>
 if(getComputedStyle(document.body).scrollBehavior === 'smooth'){
   console.log('This browser supports scrollBehavior smooth');
 }
</script>
```

Comment: What browsers change this attribute?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-behavior

This you can check in "I can use". The idea here is not to know which browser supports this, but to detect if the client browser has implemented this feature. If the property was calculated on the element, you can assume that it has the implementation.

Comment: I've tried using it in browsers that support scroll behavior and it doesn't work so I'm curious if you got this working in some browser.

Comment: `element` here, is a reference of a HTML element, for example: `var element = document.querySelector('a')`. But that element must have the scrollBehavior property predefined as 'smooth' in the CSS. If the browser is able to set the property, it is because it supports it. It was clear?

Comment: I will try to explain it better in my example

Comment: That makes sense. I now understand what you're answer is suggesting. However, I don't think it really answers the question being asked: how to detect if a browser (like Firefox) has smooth scrolling built in by default.

Comment: The question is "But it is of course a bit dumb to have a smooth scroll script active if the browser already does this by default. Is there a way I can detect if a browser already has a smooth scrolling feature enabled?" And I think that this solution detects if the browser has the "smooth scroll" built in. However, in the original code example, Svish was redoing a behavior that is now standard in most browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. Unfortunately there are no standards for these types of things. However there are work arounds, one of which you are already doing: browser sniffing.

Basically, that's about as advanced as this kind of detection goes because some browsers don't yet even support smooth scrolling officially or without experimental developments (like Chromium). And standards won't be set unless the majority are on the same page. Not only that but it also comes down to GPU hardware abilities as some devices and computers struggle with smooth scrolling and animations. So technically speaking, even if a browser did support smooth scrolling, who's to say the device or desktop running it can render fast enough to even display the effect. That's another bottle neck.

I believe someday in the future there will be more of a need for browser feature specifications such as this to better improve user interactions, but until that day you're doing it right.

Comment: So, it's now someday in the future, and this is an actual issue. The implementation of smooth scrolling is poorly done and causes unfortunate side effects when looking at wheel events.